# Why do some primitives have byte-codes and some do not?

Tags: r

I've noticed that when I call `args` on **some** of the primitive functions, byte-codes show up as well.  But on other primitives, no byte-code appears.  For example

```
args(length)
# function (x) 
# NULL
args(list)
# function (...) 
# NULL
# <bytecode: 0x44a0f38>
```

**Why is that?**

At first I thought it might be related to the `...` argument, but the following disproves that theory.

```
args(dim)
# function (x) 
# NULL
args(unclass)
# function (x) 
# NULL
# <bytecode: 0x44a0450>
```

It's confusing to me that a byte-code only shows up in some of these, and not in others.  I  have always been under the impression that all primitives are special and that they all share the same "attributes" (for lack of a better word, not the actual R attributes).

Comment: I guess the printing difference is for more historical reason. `args` is more used for console printing, maybe use `formals` to get more coherent output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As agstudy noted, this is an oddity related to how `args` prints things.  That is, whether `args` includes a bytecode line in its output isn't a reliable indicator of whether or not the function was byte compiled.  compare:

```
args(writeLines)
## function (text, con = stdout(), sep = "\n", useBytes = FALSE) 
##   NULL

writeLines
## function (text, con = stdout(), sep = "\n", useBytes = FALSE) 
## {
##   if (is.character(con)) {
##     con <- file(con, "w")
##     on.exit(close(con))
##   }
##   .Internal(writeLines(text, con, sep, useBytes))
## }
## <bytecode: 0x000000001bf3aeb0>
```

---

We can compare printing of a bytecode line for `args` vs. standard function printing.

```
arg_shows_bytecode <- function(fn)
{
  output <- capture.output(args(fn))
  grepl("^<bytecode", output[length(output)])
}

printing_shows_bytecode <- function(fn)
{
  output <- capture.output(print(fn))
  length(output) > 1 && grepl("^<bytecode", output[length(output) - 1])   
}

base_fns <- Filter(is.function, mget(ls(baseenv()), baseenv()))
yn_args <- vapply(base_fns, arg_shows_bytecode, logical(1))
yn_print <- vapply(base_fns, printing_shows_bytecode, logical(1))
```

It's worth noting that all functions where `args` shows bytecode information are primitives.

```
head(base_fns[yn_args])
## $`%*%`
## function (x, y)  .Primitive("%*%")
## 
## $as.call
## function (x)  .Primitive("as.call")
## 
## $attr
## function (x, which, exact = FALSE)  .Primitive("attr")
## 
## $`attr<-`
## function (x, which, value)  .Primitive("attr<-")
## 
## $attributes
## function (obj)  .Primitive("attributes")
## 
## $`attributes<-`
## function (obj, value)  .Primitive("attributes<-")
```

The converse isn't true: some base functions where `args` doesn't show bytecode information are primitives; others are not.

```
yn_prim <- vapply(base_fns, is.primitive, logical(1))
table(yn_args, yn_print, yn_prim)
## , , yn_prim = FALSE
## 
##        yn_print
## yn_args FALSE TRUE
## FALSE       0  988
## TRUE        0    0
## 
## , , yn_prim = TRUE
## 
##        yn_print
## yn_args FALSE TRUE
## FALSE     119    0
## TRUE       63    0
```

So non-primitive functions in the base package are all compiled, but `args` doesn't mention it.  Primitive functions don't show a bytecode message when printed, and only sometimes show a bytecode message when called with args.

Comment: Simpler explanation: this is a bug in `args()`. It should never display bytecode compilation status, because that's not a property of the argument list of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report. This behavior is unintentional (a bug, as Hadley says), it is not consistent internally as the bytecode address is displayed only for builtins and specials and only when their formals are in `.ArgsEnv` (they can also be in `.GenericArgsEnv`). Now fixed in R-devel. Bug reports are best directed right into R bugzilla (R-devel mailing list works as well).